# how to handle long running commnads in ansilbe?

Tags: ansible, apt

To make sure that the time consuming commands like (apt-mirror) which takes hours to sync, is there any better approach to handle them so that the anible would continue to work.

Comment: Depends what you are after. Do you want the playbook/command to keep on running or do you want to launch the command and let it live its own life? Either way, this is going to be resolved with [asynchronous tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-playbook-tasks)

Comment: I would like the playbook command to run next plays and run the (apt-mirror) in the backgroud if there is no error for first 5 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, you are looking for an [asynchronous task](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-playbook-tasks), those kind of task can come with a sibling, which is `async_status`, in order to check (back) on the status of a registered asynchronous task.

Here is a simple example on how it could look:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - name: Run an async task
      shell: sleep 30
      ## Let it run for 5 minutes
      async: 300
      poll: 0
      ## We are registering the task, so we can get its status later
      register: long_runnging_task

    - debug:
        msg: "I am another task running in between"

    - name: Check on an async task
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ long_runnging_task.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      ## Recheck this job status
      ## 30 times, leaving 10 seconds
      ## of interval between each retry 
      retries: 30
      delay: 10
```

Which gives the recap:

```
PLAY [localhost] *************************************************************

TASK [Run an async task] *****************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  msg: I am another task running in between

TASK [Check on an async task] ************************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Check on an async task (30 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Check on an async task (29 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: [localhost]: Check on an async task (28 retries left).
changed: [localhost]
```